# How to change a property of ViewModel property and make the change reflects on the bound control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

I'm writing a windows Phone app; and as a good citizen I'm using MVVM pattern :) Being not so expert in MVVM, I faced the following issue that I hope I find solution for here.

I have the following code:

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding MyPOCO}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsActive}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private POCO myPOCO;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.myPOCO = new POCO();
        this.ToggleActiveStatusCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ToggleActiveStatus);
    }

    public POCO MyPOCO
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myPOCO;
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand ToggleActiveStatusCommand { get; private set; }

    private void ToggleActiveStatus()
    {
        this.MyPOCO.IsActive = !this.MyPOCO.IsActive;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.MyPOCO.IsActive);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyPOCO");
    }
}
```

**POCO**

```
public class POCO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to change the TextBlock text as the value of IsActive changes... how to do that? I mean other than exposing the required properties from POCO as properties to ViewModel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to implement properties in your ViewModel that call into the POCO properties unless you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your POCO which then goes against MVVM where your Model should just hold your data and your ViewModel is the glue that links the Model with the View.

Creating properties in your ViewModel may seem like alot of additional work but it does add the benefit of being able to define many ViewModels based on a single Model. So in the specific ViewModel you only expose properties that you need rather than everything the Model can offer you.

Once you have defined your ViewModel properties, you may need to set the Mode of your Binding to TwoWay so that the UI can be updated when the underlying ViewModel properties change.

Comment: can't I just say: re-bind everthing as my DataContext was changed; Something like what I was trying to do in `this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyPOCO")`?

Comment: If you created a variable for your ViewModel instance, you could set the DataContext are you are doing, then make the POCO change and then set the DataContext to NULL and then set the DataContext back to your variable, which would rebind and therefore present the change.

Comment: I didn't quite get that. Who's going to set the DataContext to NULL? I can't access it from my ViewModel and my View code behind wouldn't know if something has changed. If it was WPF I may take advantage of `NotifyOnSourceUpdated`, but in WP7 I don't have this luxury... or am I missing something here?